# Call to undefined function menu_load() in .../public_html/includes/menu.inc on line 579

Tags: .htaccess

I really need your help. Actually, my journey begin with the installation Drupal and some modules. After a couple of days I suddenly get an issue "500 Internal Server Error".

I asked my hosting provider why this happened, they said "That because of the file .htaccess and you should add to this file php display error". So i did this and I get a new issue :

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function menu_load() in public_html/includes/menu.inc on line 579.

By the way that's line 579 `else {$return = $function($value);}`. 
P.S I am a beginner in PHP. I really want to study Drupal more and create cool sites, but this problem...

Comment: What changes did you make to .htaccess? Did you use an auto-installer or did you FTP drupal?

Comment: I didn't make any changes to .htaccess. I Use FTP for files and Drupal Core 7.

Answer (score 0):

Here are few tips:

- Make sure your Drupal core has all the files in the right place (especially menu module).
- Make sure your imported database is in UTF-8 format.
- Upgrade your Drupal core to the latest version (`drush fr && drush up drupal`).
- Clear all your caches (`drush -y cc all`), including your memcached (`killall memcached`).
- Rebuild your registry by using [Registry Rebuild](https://www.drupal.org/project/registry_rebuild).
- Ff you're using modules which are implementing `drupal_bootstrap()` (such as Secure Site), disable them.
- Try disabling your PHP cache engines (such as XCache, Zend optimizer) to see if that's the problem.
- Test it on different environment/machine.
- Check your [database collation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5906585/55075) (it should be case insensitive, e.g.: `general_ci`).
- Eventually restore your database from the point where it was working before.